# How do I save cookies from a response to a cURL request using php?

Tags: php, curl

Im using curl through php to fetch a url. I am successfully able to download the page, headers and all. However, the cookies returned by any page do not get saved to the specified file. I've checked permissions etc, and nothing seems out of the ordinary. I am beginning to think something is off in my code.

```
$get_cookie_page = 'http://www.google.ca';
echo curl_download($get_cookie_page);

function curl_download($Url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
  $http_headers = array(
                    'Host: www.google.ca',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
                    'Accept: */*',
                    'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Connection: keep-alive'
                  );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $output;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks good - are you 1000% sure there are some cookies to save?

Comment: Curl won't write session cookies out to the file, only permanent ones.

Comment: @DaveRandom:Yes there are cookies to be saved.

Comment: @MarcB: I tried it on a bunch of different uris that return permanent cookies too. Cookies don't get saved there either.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, but try adding in CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, pointing at the same cookie.txt. JAR is the correct option for saving cookies, but who knows... maybe your curl library is wonky or something.

Comment: Make sure you have write permissions on cookie.txt try CHMOD'ing it to 777

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all the help. However, the problem was something else entirely. I probably should have mentioned that I am working on a Windows server and cURL was unable to read the path to `cookie.txt`.

Using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
```

instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use an absolute path to the cookie jar file so that you're sure where it is saved and thus you know you have the right permission to write there.

curl stores all cookies it knows of to the file, including so called session cookies (that are without an expiry time)