# How can set cookies with token id

Tags: php, curl

I want to auto login on other website. I am using Curl php for this. I have print the output its working fine . it returns the array properly but i need to set cookies with token id. cookies like  "user_XXXX" and token in it.
my code is :-

```
$uname='';
$pwd='FFFFFFFF';
$url_post='https://api.test.com/v3/public/loginGrant?site_address=example.test.com&username=xxxx.com&password=BdXXXX';
$ckfile = "cookies.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lab.example.com/example2-crm/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$uname:$pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $ckfile);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$arr=json_decode($result);
$arr= (array) $arr;
print_r($arr);
```

how can i set cookies in it and login the website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917970/how-do-i-save-cookies-from-a-response-to-a-curl-request-using-php

Comment: i have used your reference link and it returns array like 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.11.10 Date: Tue, 11 Apr 2017 09:58:24 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 1839 Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 19:16:07 GMT ETag: "58e7e577-72f" Link: ; rel="canonical" Accept-Ranges: bytes  but i cant logged in

Comment: how can i auto logged in on the website