# How can I check which cookies are loaded on a website due a PHP CRON

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, cron

I want to check, on a daily basis, which cookies are loaded in a website. I want this as a kind of monitoring like https://www.cookiebot.com/ does. I don't want to copy them but only use some functionality to build in out internal monitoring tool.

So what I want to do is run a CRON every x days to check which cookies are loaded in some websites we monitor. I also want to check cookies loaded by external javascripts like google analytics or facebook

I was thinking of some kind of server side rendering of the website to find out which cookies are loaded. Is this possible? Which option do you prefer?

I would like to use your knowledge to solve this challenge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Is it possible?"_ - Yes. However, I don't see the point of doing this several times a day, though. Are you expecting the code on the sites to change that often? Either way, just do a request (with something like cURL) and save the cookies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save cookies from a response to a cURL request using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917970/how-do-i-save-cookies-from-a-response-to-a-curl-request-using-php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Several times a day will not be case I guess. You are right in that. And it's not a duplicate. I also want cookies set by javascript libraries and plugins to be caught. The other question only gets the SESSION $_COOKIE or other server side set cookies.

Comment: If you want javascript generated cookies, your need a javascript engine etc. You need to do some research into that. The question just became _way_ too broad for SO.